# Generate binary values within nested dictionary from two dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-loops

two input dictionaries are:
input dictionary 1

```
d1 = {'ad':['gf','tr','st'],'ft':['te','gr','mf']}
```

input dictionary 2

```
d2 = {'ad':['te','mr','lr','kr','er'],'ft':['ty','yr','qf','fg','jh']}
```

required output dictionary is

```
output={'ad':{'gf':1,'tr':1,'st':1,'te':0,'mr':0,'lr':0,'kr':0,'er':0},
    'ft':{'te':1,'gr':1,'mf':1,'ty':0,'yr':0,'qf':0,'fg':0,'jh':0}}
```

Is there anyway to produce this output dictionary from these two input dictionaries. In output, if the inner dictionary value belong to dictionary 1 then its value is 1 in output dictionary. If it belongs to dictionary 2 then its value is 0.

Comment: It can be done definitely. But did you try first?

Comment: Is the given data structure the only structure a possible solution should support or is it required to handle multiple dictionaries with nested lists dynamically? Depending on this, a solution might become more complex or  a simple approach might be usable. What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d1 = {'ad':['gf','tr','st'],'ft':['te','gr','mf']}
d2 = {'ad':['te','mr','lr','kr','er'],'ft':['ty','yr','qf','fg','jh']}

output = {}
for k in d1:
    output[k] = {k2: 1 for k2 in d1[k]}
    output[k].update({k2:0 for k2 in d2[k]})
```

output:

```
{'ad': {'gf': 1, 'tr': 1, 'st': 1, 'te': 0, 'mr': 0, 'lr': 0, 'kr': 0, 'er': 0}, 'ft': {'te': 1, 'gr': 1, 'mf': 1, 'ty': 0, 'yr': 0, 'qf': 0, 'fg': 0, 'jh': 0}}
```

Comment: Do not use `dict.keys()`, iterate over dict `for k in d1`.

Comment: @OlvinRoght other than "extra characters", is there a reason to prefer one over the other?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, take a look on [Dictionary Iterators](https://peps.python.org/pep-0234/#dictionary-iterators) section in PEP 234.

Comment: @OlvinRoght ah, I never knew `.keys()` is much slower, since I only iterate over the dict itself if ever I need to. Thanks!